# Global pointer to a statically allocated struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want a global pointer to a statically allocated struct.

This compiles

```
struct sa{
    int a, b;
    char const* c;
};
struct sa* sap = &(struct sa){42,43,"x"};
```

but is it legal & portable C, or do I have to do something like?:

```
static struct sa x = {42,43,"x"};
struct sa* sap2  = &x;
```

Comment: you need your 2nd example (declare x and then take it's addr)

Comment: Are you sure, @bolov?  It's not immediately obvious to me that you should not be able to take the address of a compound literal.  I'll need to research it.

Comment: Are you asking if applying the address-of operator `&` against a [compound literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) is legal ? Their value-category is *lvalue*, after all, so that should be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, according to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf, 6.5.2.5 Compound literals, 5:

> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object
>   initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs
>   outside the body of a function, the object has static storage
>   duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
>   the enclosing block.

it's legal when used in the global scope.

Thanks [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) for letting me know the name of the construct so I could look it up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's legal when used in the global scope, but it takes the address of a literal, so if you try to change the value, you will get an error.  Although, reading your question, since a literal is static, it might work for you.  As far as good coding practices are concerned, you might want to use

`const struct sa* sap = &(struct sa){42,43,"x"};`

or, preferably,

`static struct sa x = {42,43,"x"};
const struct sa* sap2  = &x;`

Comment: Interesting point and I'm glad you brought it up. But according to the standard draft in the link of my answer, the compound literal will only be read-only if it's marked const (The string literal member may always be read-only). Gcc agrees and doesn't put the compound literal in read-only memory.